# Does Cassandra Supports PITR (Point in time Recovery)?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Below is my commitlog_archiving.properties configuration

Do we need to use both restore command and restore directories?

```
archive_command=/backup/archive_commit_log.sh
restore_command=/backup/move_achive_to_live.sh
restore_directories=/u01/cassandra/arch/
restore_point_in_time=2020:12:18 15:24:00
```

archive_commit_log.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/* /u01/cassandra/arch/
```

move_achive_to_live.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -f /u01/cassandra/arch/* /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/
```

i have cleared the existing commit log directory and restarted but it hasnt restored to that point.
Am i missing something

Comment: Did you also clean your data directory? If not, all commitlogs replayed are likely already in your sstables so that won't work.

Waht did you exactly do?

Comment: @ Mandraenke is it mandate to clean all databases( i.e .db files) in  data directory like say i have abc db so before doing restoring using PITR should i need to delete abc directory in data directory?
and perform PITR otherwise i.e  if i dont delete data directory it wont work?

Comment: what i have done is i change commit log settings like enabled restore command and mentioned PITR time and archived the commit logs and try to delete some data at some point and want to restore to that point before the delete operation happend.so i stopped cassandra delete the existing commit logs and" but here i haven't deleted the existing db in data directory" and  started the cassandra while starting its copied the archived logs to commit logs directory but showing logs as "Log replay complete, 0 replayed mutations".

Comment: let say i want to restore from snapshot to some point as base backup  and using commit log after that in this case also shld i need remove data directory which were result snapshot restore?